# Getting the outer path only of a 'merged' Core Graphics path

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I have created a path in Core Graphics to draw a heart shape, however, to do this I have created a diamond shape and 2 circles, this image looks great, but I just want to know if it is possible to get the 'actual' heart shape from this CGPath/CGContext.

Here is the code to draw a heart (for anyone interested), this shape is the one I want to create as the connection between the heart 'humps' and the pointed triangle are smooth:

```
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(heartPath, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20));
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(heartPath, NULL, CGRectMake(20, 0, 20, 20));

CGPathMoveToPoint(heartPath, NULL, 37.5, 16.5);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(heartPath, NULL, 37.5, 16.5);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(heartPath, NULL, 20, 37.5);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(heartPath, NULL, 2.5, 16.5);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(heartPath, NULL, 20, 10);

CGPathCloseSubpath(heartPath);
```

[Produces this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2qtvger1xc8k1cz/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2016%20Jun%202012%2000.48.42.png)

And this code:

```
CGPathAddArc(heartPath, NULL, 10, 10, 10, M_PI, 0, false); // Left hump
CGPathAddArc(heartPath, NULL, 30, 10, 10, M_PI, 0, false); // Right hump
CGPathAddLineToPoint(heartPath, NULL, 20, 37.5); // Pointy end

CGPathCloseSubpath(heartPath);
```

[Produces this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2t7c3r9mrv02aoe/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2016%20Jun%202012%2000.48.04.png)

Is this possible and easy to implement? If so how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no public function to compute the union of multiple paths (nor any private function as far as I know).  Computing the union of bezier paths is a hard, complicated problem.

Depending on what you want to do, there may be easier ways.  What do you want to do with the union path?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing 3 different shapes, you should draw a single shape by doing something like this:

```
CGPathAddArc(heartPath, NULL, 10, 10, 10, M_PI, 0, false); // Left hump
CGPathAddArc(heartPath, NULL, 30, 10, 10, M_PI, 0, false); // Right hump
CGPathAddLineToPoint(heartPath, NULL, 20, 37.5); // Pointy end
CGPathCloseSubpath(heartPath);
```

I'm not positive all the values are correct, but basically you want to draw only part of the circle, so use `CGPathAddArc()` twice, and then a line to the point at the pointy end, and then close it.

Comment: Yeah, initially this is what I tried to do (although the `CGPathAddArc` was confusing the hell out of me! My only problem is that this creates two semi circles on the heart rather than making it look completely rounded - updated code to show difference